# jquery ajax submit handler php script not executing

Tags: php, forms

I am working on a contact form for sending mail.I used jquery ajax submitHandler for this.But the php script is not executing.
In the response area of network in the google chrome (Inspect element)
the response is the php code itself. ie, it is not executing.

Here is the attached image
[image]

And here is the script

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.validator.setDefaults({
                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "contact_form.php",

                            data: $("#contactform").serialize()
                        }).done(function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                            swal("Mail Send!", "We will back to you soon", 'success');
                            $('#contactform').trigger("reset");

                        });
                    }
                });
 $("#contactform").validate({
                    rules:
                            {
                                name: {required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 50},
                                email: {required: true, email: true},
                                suburb: {required: true, minlength: 4},
                                phonenumber: {required: true, number: true, minlength: 4},
                                message: {required: false, maxlength: 300}
                            },
                    errorClass: "error",
                    highlight: function (label) {
                        $(label).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                    },
                    success: function (label) {
                        label
                                // .text('Seems Perfect!').addClass('valid')
                                .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');

                    }
                }

                );

            });



        </script>
```

And the php for testing is

```html
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: It seems that your server is not executing PHP files.. make sure you have PHP installed and running

Comment: In addition to @MateiMihai, maybe it is just an issue with the file extension (e.g. `.php` is parsed, and `. php5` not), so check for a possible `AddHandler` directive as well. What happens if you call `contact_form.php` directly?

Comment: @MateiMihai I am working on localhost.And php is installed in it.The php is executing when it is running directly

Comment: @jan I tried to call the contact_form.php file directly on the browser and it is just downloading the php file.please help

Comment: If PHP is not executing, this has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is at the server side (definitely not at the client). It may be caused by e.g.

1. incorrectly configured file handlers on the web server
2. incorrect file encoding
3. incorrect file permission settings

Comment: Exactly I was due to the server side issue.Guess that php doesnt have the permission for execution